# email with approval link

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have, say a supplier, who logs into to the site and fills out a form and an email is sent to administrator when submitted, but this is only added to the "Approved" list when an administrator (person who receives this email) allows. I want to know how to send a link in an email whereby when the person clicks the link it approves this form for this particular supplier... at the moment I have this:

```
MailingManager.SendEmail(toAddresses, fromAddress, "Approval", "<a href=http://localhost:53048/Website/Site/PurchasersSuppliers/CreateSuppliers.aspx?SectionID=537  </a>; 
This is an email to ask for confirmation, null, templateID);
```

So I know you can add HTML to the body of the mail....but how do I get it so that when the link in the body is clicked that I get some sort of way of indicating to the database whether this particular record is approved or not?

Answer (score 2):

you can pass html code as below

```
MailingManager.SendEmail(toAddresses, fromAddress, "Approval", "<a href='http://localhost:53048/Website/Site/PurchasersSuppliers/CreateSuppliers.aspx?SectionID=537&UserID=12&SupplierID=2'>This is an email to ask for confirmation  </a>", null, templateID);
```

when u send link in mail , and then from email link open by supplier , its redirect to your application page CreateSuppliers.aspx.

Now on CreateSuppliers.aspx page u can handle event in page load itself. you can pass even more argument in query string to accomplish your task.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DoSomething(Request["SectionID"]);
    }
}

private void DoSomething(string SectionID)
{ 
    // make database call against SectionID and fetch whether its approved or not.
}
```

Hope this will helps you....

Comment: SectionID isnt specific to a user or supplier, its just the partuicular section of the website the user is in...Is it possible to have two queryString parameters?

Comment: Although this will work, I would advise against just allowing the parameters being passed as a querystring value to a page which is open to anyone. e.g. Anyone could start passing in any values for "SectionID" or other querystring values, and messing with your database. I would simply send an email with the details, and tell the administrator to log into a website to validate.

Comment: yes you can append more query string parameters in html by which u can get data as request query string on page. I have modify my answer as per this suggestion (look at MailingManager.SendEmail function) ..please look it that helps you

Comment: I Agree with Tim. Also, I would prefer to display the page and make the user perform a postback by clicking on Confirm button. This would prevent XSRF attack. The page itself will be rendered only to authorized users who can approve.

Comment: lets encrypt those querystring data using encrypting algorithm.

Comment: thats understandable, Tim, but is there anyway for the administrator to approve directly from the email by pressing a link or button?

Comment: How would i do that, Prakash?

Comment: you can encrypt and decrypt algorithm supported by namespace System.Security.Cryptography.  you can get more details how to encrypt and decrypt values visit my blog link http://prakashpatani.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-using.html